# Best way to handle client disconnection using TCP socket

Tags: c++, tcp

I manage to create basic remote administrator tools and it's working fine, I'm using basic tcp socket and multithreading in c++. It's like 90% done with a few functions I can used to remotely use it, but my software didn't have anything that can detect client disconnection except when the client are manually close which the client will send disconnection message to the server, but when the disconnection happen when the user unplug the network or something else, what is the best way to handle it, I'm looking for a professional way to do it, like if the client disconnected, the server will instantly detect which client disconnected.

Answer (score 3):

Idle TCP connections don't have to send any data for the connection to be maintained.  The scenario you are trying to detect is called a "half-open" connection.  There's a chart of options in the Stevens book in chapter 7.5 (that's page 186 in mine).  The end result is this:

1. if you are actively sending data the connection will timeout waiting for an ack from the remote system (timeout is system dependent, but is usually in the range of minutes).
2. if you have keep-alives enabled (and they are properly supported) the system will timeout after 2 *hours* of inactivity.  non-response from the remote system will cause a timeout
3. if you don't have keep-alives enabled and you are not sending data there is no way to detect a lost client.

Which means, if you want to close connections relatively quickly on disconnection you need to add your own way.  I usually force one side to send a heartbeat of some kind.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia says not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_half-open and Stevens seems to agree: "But if the client host crashes, the server process will never know about it, and the server will continually wait for input that will never arrive.  This is called a *half-open connection."

Comment: I beg your pardon. I see I've been using that term wrongly for decades.

Answer (score 2):

Like @EJP says, there is no way to instantaneously detect a hard disconnect, since the local computer can't see what is happening across the network, it can only see that its outgoing TCP packets aren't being ACK'd anymore.  It has no way of knowing if the lack of ACKs is due to a temporary problem (like an overloaded router dropping some packets, or an Ethernet cable that was pulled out and then quickly plugged back in again) or a more permanent one (like the remote computer crashing, being permanently powered down, or becoming disconnected from the network).

What you can do is make sure that your local app is always periodically sending data over the TCP socket -- either actual data, or if you don't have any actual data to send, send some dummy bytes that the client will know to ignore.  These "heartbeat messages" could be sent once per minute, or once every few seconds, depending on how much extra bandwidth you are willing to use up for this purpose.

What the periodic sending of TCP data will do is force your local computer's TCP stack to watch for ACKs corresponding to the sent packets; if it doesn't receive the expected ACKs, it will resend the packets, and after a few rounds of resending, it will give up and close the TCP connection.  Most TCP stacks will give up after a couple of minutes of no ACKs being received.

If "a couple of minutes" isn't quick enough for you, you might instead require the remote program to send some sort of data to your program every few seconds, and force-close the TCP socket if you haven't received any data from the client for at least (so many seconds).  Note that depending on the number of seconds you set as your timeout, this might cause "false positives" where your program force-closes TCP connections that were actually still viable but were temporarily bogged down; that may or may not be acceptable for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't detect it instantaneously unless the client closes the connection properly. You have to use read timeouts, and react correctly to all other errors returned by send() or recv(), i.e. by closing the socket.